# Dealing with Log4J Bug using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver-security

Are there any guidelines yet on how to deal with the Log4J bug in GeoServer?

https://thenextweb.com/news/log4j-bug-internet-open-source-contributors-analysis

Comment: this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325735/geoserver-replacing-log4j-1-2-17-with-2-15-0) is worth reading

Answer (score 6):

There are significant changes in the way logging is done in the switch from log4j v1 (the one GeoServer uses) and log4j v2 (the one with the latest CVE). While GeoServer is immune to the RCE vulnerability mentioned in the question, there are still some small risks in using the old (and EOL) version we do use.

So as a temporary mitigation Andrea Aime has made a fork of the current log4j v1 trunk removing the network elements that might be abused by an attacker that has access to your GeoServer machine. See https://github.com/aaime/log4j for the tree you will need to clone and build. This will generate a new jar called log4j-1.2.17-norce.jar which you should replace log4j-1.2.17.jar with. You can download the jar from https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17-norce.jar to save building it.

If you make use of GeoServer then you might like to contribute to the developers (or via the OSGEO foundation) to help support the work involved in reducing the technical debt of the project like updating the logging library.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the quick response. Can you help us building that package. Just let me know how many coffees needed and I will get them to you.

Comment: See the blog post as well http://geoserver.org/announcements/2021/12/13/logj4-rce-statement.html

Comment: @Ian, If the Geoserver is installed via .exe do we still need to stop/restart the Tomcat before and after replacing the .jar file? (I cannot find Tomcat installed on server were our Geoserver is installed)

Comment: You will need to find it in the jetty install that the exe installer creates.

Comment: Can I just stop the Geoserver's Windows Service and do this process and start again. I am unable to find tomcat (in jetty installed with geoserver)

Comment: if you are using Jetty then you need to restart that instead of tomcat - I just don't expect people to be running jetty in production so didn't mention it